# How to set up an end-to-end SNMP data collection system to cloud?

Tags: networking, snmp, cloud, network-monitoring, diagnostic

**Aim:** We are creating a cloud server which will collect diagnostic data (like bytes exchanged, SNR) from remote SNMP enabled network devices (like Routers, Switches).

The SNMP devices may be located in a private network.

We discussed with a cable vendor who quoted,

> SNMP on modems is only accessible via the modem IP, which is
>   traditionally a private IP within an MSO. Companies will generally
>   deploy a probe or agent on-site that collects the SNMP data and
>   delivers it back to their main operation.
>
> SNMP proxies are also a possibility.

He talks about about *deploy probes, proxing, on site agent*.

We want to know how those mechanisms are actually implemented in detail.

Some references or few lines of introduction about the set up would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"deploy a probe or agent on-site" -- install something inside the network that does the collection, then return the data to the management station.

"SNMP proxies" -- software which receives an SNMP request from the outside, redirects it to the device to be monitored, and then returns the response to the original requestor.